# What is this called?

Tags: terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the term for a factorial type operation, but with summation instead of products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/what-is-the-term-for-a-factorial-type-operation-but-with-summation-instead-of-pr)

I am looking for the name of an operation similar to factorial.

Factorial would be like:
6! = 6*5*4*3*2*1

but if the operator is "+" and not "*", like:
6+5+4+3+2+1

What would I call this?

Edit:
Sorry, it seems this was a duplicate question. The answer appears to be "nth triangular number". Although that's really not as satisfying and concise as the word "factorial".

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^6 n$ Maybe?

Comment: We do not need an additional terminology to describe this sum, because it can be summed to give a "closed-form answer", i.e., an answer that can be written using simpler functions like $+$ and $\times$ and $/$.  The sum is equal to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Instead of $n!$ why not write $n\triangle$?