# Is there a way to quickly know the number of elements on a triangle type?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the term for a factorial type operation, but with summation instead of products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/what-is-the-term-for-a-factorial-type-operation-but-with-summation-instead-of-pr)

I don't technically know the mathematical term, but imagine:

```
         X
        X X
       X X X
      X X X X
     X X X X X
    X X X X X X
   X X X X X X X
  X X X X X X X X
 X X X X X X X X X
X X X X X X X X X X
```

taking the last row that holds 10 elements, the total will be:

```
10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
```

witch totals **55**

just like there is the factor sign `10!` that tells us the same but multiplying the numbers, is there a technical term / function, to by other means calculate the total **55**?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is, the [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and they can be calculated very easily: $$T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$ Your particular example is $T_{10}=(10\cdot 11)/2=55$.