# Is there a standard name or shorthand for "plustorial"?

Tags: notation, terminology, factorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the term for a factorial type operation, but with summation instead of products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/what-is-the-term-for-a-factorial-type-operation-but-with-summation-instead-of-p)

We're all familiar with factorial:
$$n>0,\quad  n! = n \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times (n-(n-1))$$

I've occasionally seen "plustorial": 
$$n>0,\quad  n(\mathrm{plustorial}) = n + (n-1) + \ldots + (n-(n-1))$$

Some quick web searching indicates that there is some non-standard but somewhat common usage of the term "plustorial" to describe this, with shorthand being a double-dagger or an exclaimation point having a "+" rather than a dot beneath the vertical mark.

My question is: Is there a "real" standard name for this process and is there a standard corresponding shorthand? I understand that it could be written in sigma notation, was curious about something more terse.

Comment: You might want to read a little about triangular numbers. $$1+2+3+\cdots+n = T_n = {n+1 \choose 2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: thank you, vote to close as "exact duplicate" please. I would think I shouldn't delete the question because others may search using "plustorial" as I did.