# 'Plus' Operator analog of the factorial function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the term for a factorial type operation, but with summation instead of products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/what-is-the-term-for-a-factorial-type-operation-but-with-summation-instead-of-p)

Is there a similar function for the addition operator as there is the factorial function for the multiplication operator?

For factorials it is 5! = 5*4*3*2*1, is there a function that would do 5+4+3+2+1?

Thanks,

Comment: yes, n(n+1)/2 :)

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know we haven't given that expression a name since we may write it explicitly as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^ni = {n+1 \choose 2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$

Comment: we can do the same thing using a \Pi, why do we have the factorial function ..? Though it's not closed form yes.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf yes that is true. Pure speculation on my part, but  writing $1\cdot 2\cdots n$ is not "nice enough" notation and $n!$ comes up "more frequently" that a shorter notation was needed. If one really needs a shorter notation for $\sum_1^n i$, I supposed one would just refer to it as $T_n$, the $n$th triangle number.

Comment: mhmm I've seen that notation before somewhere :)