# When is the factorial of a number triangular?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Triangular Factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40945/triangular-factorials)

Extending [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238462/when-is-a-factorial-of-a-number-equal-to-its-triangular-number), what are the solutions $(m,n)$ of this equation?

$\sum_{k=1}^m{k} = n!$

I know $(1,1)$, $(3,3)$, and $(15,5)$.  Are there any more?  How can I prove the solution set is finite?

Comment: The abstract of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2006-358-04/S0002-9947-05-03780-3/S0002-9947-05-03780-3.pdf) linked by [one of the answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/40968/1284) claims that there are only a finite number of solutions for some cases, but not including this one.  This is definitely an exact duplicate but I don't think any of the answers to the other are satisfactory.