# Factorial, but with addition

Tags: arithmetic, factorial

Is there a notation for addition form of factorial?

$$5! = 5\times4\times3\times2\times1$$

That's pretty obvious. But I'm wondering what I'd need to use to describe

$$5+4+3+2+1$$

like the factorial $5!$ way.

EDIT: I know about the formula. I want to know if there's a short notation.

Comment: $1+2+\dots+n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$; there's no need for a special notation.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/60578/439

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap I'm asking about it's notation...

Comment: The sigma notation is a notation for it.

Comment: Did you read the answers in the linked post?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Yes, but I wanted to know if there's a simpler way like factorial. Using just a single character... In Sigma Notation, it looks like M rolled over after getting drunk and numbers are partying around it. Sorry if that sounded sarcastic, but yeah.

Comment: So, you didn't see the answer which described that Knuth suggested the notation "$n?$" ?

Comment: Also... I think that you should rather get used to seeing $\Sigma$, $\Pi$, and other Greek letters with some regularity if you are interested in mathematics. Overcoming some minor notational prejudices early will prove its own reward.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Actually I did. I was googling about it. I suppose $n?$ is the closest thing to what I asked for. You're right. I should. I was just working on something and spent few pages on it. It's just um.. consuming writing the same thing over and over again. Wanted an easy fix, like $n!$. I'll use $n?$ for now. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: If I might suggest, you could always define a function for the purpose if the question marks make your math look cluttered or strange. Given the fact that these are triangular numbers, $\tau(n)$ would be appropriate and distinctive.

Comment: As a fun side note, we have the [Exponential factorial](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Exponential_factorial): $$a_5=5^{4^{3^{2^1}}}$$ and beyond that we have the [Hyperfactorial array notation](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperfactorial_array_notation).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It is called the $n$th *triangle number* and it can be written as $\binom{n+1}2$, as a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: why would it be called a "triangle number"?

Comment: @khaverim Check this [image](http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/nth%20triangle%20number-01.jpg). This is something I've come up with some time ago to visualize and understand how the calculation works. I've literally spent an hour or so to think that, becasuse I had nowhere to look then. And I'm guessing it's called triangle number(s) becase you can treat the number set as the half of a rectangle, a triangle.

Comment: I assumed it was a triangle number due to the obvious relationship to Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the notation, this is not a correct answer. I believe it should be ( ( n ( n + 1 ) ) / 2 ), not ( ( n + 1 ) / 2 ).

Comment: Berci just skipped some details. The notation is called [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: @akinuri Photobucket make the image blurry.

Comment: @BrainStorm.exe Thanks for the notification. The image at the direct link is (now) blurry, because it seems my account exceeded the free plan bandwidth (25MB/month). This [link](https://photobucket.com/gallery/user/akinuri/media/cGF0aDovbnRoIHRyaWFuZ2xlIG51bWJlci0wMS5qcGc=) seems to work fine.

Comment: This is incorrect. This not only does not get the desired result, it also doesn't get the $n$th triangle; it's just a simple linear function which better expresses "What is one more than the sum of $n$ halves?"

Comment: @BenLeggiero it's correct, it's binomial coefficient notation as pointed out by other commenters, not a linear function. It could otherwise be written as C(n+1, 2), n+1C2, etc., and translates as (n+1)!/(2(n-1)!), or n(n+1)/2

Comment: @17slim Oh! My apologies; I thought this was a fraction.

Answer (score 58):

That can be done with the formula $\frac{n^2+n}{2}$

Comment: What about doing the opposite, finding the dimensions using the output number? So far I have `floor(sqrt(2 * s))`

Comment: If the output is, say $y$ then you need to solve $n^2+n=2y$ or $(n+0.5)^2=2y+0.25$. Take square root and hope for an integer answer

Comment: This one fitted perfect for py3
`N = int(input())
for i in range(1,N+1):
    sum = ((i**2)+i)/2

print(int(sum))`

Answer (score 25):

We should also note that the factorial function has a similar look to it as the sigma summation notation; as
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=1+2+3+...+n=\sum_{k=1}^nk$$
$$n!=1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot n=\prod_{k=1}^nk$$

Answer (score 15):

$\sum_{n=1}^{k} n = 1 +2+3+\ldots+k$. Is a nice notation for it. So 
$$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = \sum_{n=1}^{5} n$$.