# Is there a way to denote the calculation $1+2+3+\dots+n$?

Tags: notation, summation, terminology

Since $n!$ represents $$1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n,$$ I am wondering if there is a way to represent  $$1+2+3+\dots+n?$$
What are some usual notations for the computation of some common sequences? Any other examples?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n i$. Also, $n(n+1)/2$. Depends on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Your sum is the [Triangle Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) $T_n$.

Comment: Only a comment, but I swear I've seen (maybe on another math.se post?) the notation $n?$ for this sum as well.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki According to Donald Knuth in Section 1.2.5 of Volume 1 of *The Art of Computer Programming*, the notation $$n? = \dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1)$$ is known as the **termial function** of $n$. However, I personally prefer the Triangular number interpretation for $T_n$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the term for a factorial type operation, but with summation instead of products?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/what-is-the-term-for-a-factorial-type-operation-but-with-summation-instead-of-p); also [Factorial, but with addition](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593318/factorial-but-with-addition)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One way to write it would be simply by using the sumation notation, meaning
$$1+2+3+\dots+n=\sum_{k=1}^n k.$$
Of course, that is equivalent to writing the factorials with the product notation, meaning
$$n!=\prod_{k=1}^n k,$$
so I don't think that is what you were asking.

If you already know that $1+2+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, then you can just write $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ instead of the sum. The fact that the sum can be expressed as this rather short fraction is in my oppinion the real reason why a shortened notation does not exist. Unlike in the case of $n!$, which cannot be expressed by a polynomial in $n$, this one can be, thus shortening the notation is not needed.

EDIT: I was of course proven wrong by Chris Culter in his answer. However, I would like to add that the notation $T_n$, where $T$ stands for triangular, is not as common as $n!$. Any mathematitian in the world will know that if you write $5!$, you really mean $5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$, however, if you say $T_n$, that notation can be used for other things, such as Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: Thanks. It makes my mind clear

Comment: whortening $\mapsto$ shortening $\:$ ? $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 28):

$T_n$, where the letter T stands for [Triangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Good answer! However, when using that notation, it is good if you always specify that by $T_n$, you mean the $n$-th triangular number (unlike with $n!$, when it is perfectly clear what you mean).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this one before I checked your reference to wiki!

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} n = 1+2+3+...+ k$$

Also, $$k! = \prod\limits_{n=1}^k n$$

Comment: Right, which is why using $\sum$ is not in the spirit of the OP's question. The evaluation $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ is closer in spirit.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to write it would be ${n+1 \choose 2}$:

${n \choose 0}=1$ for all $n$, and ${n \choose k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n \choose k}$ (with ${0 \choose k} = 0$ for $k>0$). Therefore ${n\choose 1}=n$ and thus ${n+1 \choose 2}=\sum_{k=0}^n k$. Note that this actually is $0+1+\dots+n$, but obviously the additional term $0$ doesn't change the sum.