# Prove $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ by induction, triangular numbers

Tags: induction

> Prove that the $n$-th triangular number is:
>
> $$T_n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

I did this:

Base case: $\frac{1(1+1)}{2}=1$, which is true.

Then I assumed that $T_k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is true.

$$T_{k+1} = \frac{(k+1)(k+1+1)}{2}$$

I'm not sure what to do next. What is this supposed to be equal to?

Comment: To be clear:  are you saying that you have shown that formula for $T_{k+1}$?  It;'s not clear from what you have written.

Comment: Hint:  Given the statement for $T_k$, use the fact that $T_{k+1}=(k+1)+T_k$.

Comment: @mrtaurho No because that's for the sum of the sequence

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Take a look at the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60578/what-is-the-term-for-a-factorial-type-operation-but-with-summation-instead-of-p?noredirect=1&lq=1) instead. This sequence and the triangular numbers are closely related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to think about the nature of the triangular numbers: the $n$-th triangular number is the number of dots created by $n$ layers of dots stacked upon each other: the first (top) layer has $1$ dot, the next (below it) has $2$ dots, etc. The $n$-th and last layer of the $n$-the triangular number has $n$ dots:

[image]

Now, your inductive hypothesis is that the $k$-the triangular number consists of $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ dots, i.e. that

$$T_k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

Using that hypothesis, you have to show that the $k+1$-th triangular number has $\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$ dots. But note: the $k+1$-th triangular number adds a layer of $k+1$ dots to the $k$-th triangular number. That is, we know that:

$$T_{k+1}=T_k +(k+1)$$

So, use that fact, together with the inductive hypothesis, to show what you need to show, i.e. that

$$T_{k+1}=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$$

Comment: The gist to induction is basically, write sequence for n = T_n, then sequence for n + (n+1) = T_n+1, then replace the sequence for n but with T_n, simplify, etc etc, then prove they are equal. Right?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Correct! :)

Answer (score 4):

For the inductive step, we have:

\begin{align}
T_{k+1}&=T_k+(k+1) \\
&=\frac{k(k+1)}{2} + (k+1) \\
&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}
\end{align}

This is the desired result. Hence, true by the principle of mathematical induction...